# How to keep new data in recycleView.setAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tabhost

In TabHost, I have 2 tabs (2 fragments). In tab1, inside onCreateView, I have `recycleView.setAdapter`. When I click, it loads new data then if switch from tab1 to tab2 then return to tab1, `recycleView.setAdapter` reloads the old data. 
 How can I keep new data in `recycleView` when switching from tab2 to tab1?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_position, container, false);

    recyclerViewPosition = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewPosition.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewPosition.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewPosition.setAdapter(positionAdapter);

    // searchView
    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.sview);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            final List<DataPosition> filteredModelList = filter(mPositionList, newText);
            positionAdapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
            return true;
        }
    });

    Call<Position> call = mApiService.getPositionList(strTokent);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Position>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Position> call, Response<Position> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                itemArrayList = response.body().getData().getItems();

                mPositionList.clear();
                dataPosition.clear();

                /* put id and name to hashMap*/
                for (int i = 0; i < itemArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    hashMap.put(itemArrayList.get(i).getName(), itemArrayList.get(i).getId());
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < itemArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    dataPosition.add(itemArrayList.get(j).getName());
                }

                for (String strPosition : dataPosition) {

                    mPositionList.add(new DataPosition(strPosition));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Position> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: have you try mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Please put some code from tab1 onCreateView.

Comment: Faysal Ahmed  - I've added add all code in oncreateview() menthod

Comment: Never reassign the list... `itemArrayList = response.body().getData().getItems()`... You should always use `itemArrayList.addAll(...)`

Comment: cricket_007 - but when I return to tab1 recycleview.setadater still load old data

Answer (score 0):

Clear this arraylist:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Position> call, Response<Position> response) {
    itemArrayList.clear();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        itemArrayList = response.body().getData().getItems();

        mPositionList.clear();
        dataPosition.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added itemArrayList.clear();but it not work adapter still load old data

Comment: mPositionList.clear();
        dataPosition.clear(); comment them

Comment: if i don't use them recycleview add old data every I return tab1

Comment: id 635 543 027 pass 2b2q2i

Comment: unable to connect

Comment: when you connect i no longer online. what time you online tell me then I will connect

Comment: Abhinav Gupta - do you online now My teamview Id 635 543 027 and pass f839cs